# Everytime I install django for my virtual environment I end up installing it globally. How to install django for virtual environment only?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am a beginner and trying to learn Django, for that I am working in virtual environment. Whenever I try to install Django in my virtual environment it is installed globally, which is I think I should avoid.
Here is the picture of my command prompt.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f062x.png)

Comment: Switch to Linux? Seriously ... is your Django going to be running under Windows in production? You will be best off developing in as close an environment to production as is feasible. The Linux answer, is set up the virtualenv first, then use pip from within that environment to install Django.

Comment: That is a piece of good advice from @nigel222. I had windows work laptop after joining a new company but changed it to Linux when I started Django development after having issues with path-related errors.  Having the same environment as production helps reduce errors and problems.

Comment: The picture of the question is not visible. Make sure you check if you activated the environment before installing Django. Then go for pip install.

Comment: I've used Django in visual studio under WIndows for years without major issues in a virtual environment. I use the database on a Linux Server but test the code under windows. I use Bash for the terminal windows, and activation is `source env/scripts/activate` instead of `source env/bin/activate` as under Linux. The repo is on a gitlab server which I can push with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling pip from your env folder in your command prompt and not global pip

```
pip install django

env\Scripts\pip.exe install django
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ---
First check your virtual environment is activate or not, if not use this command -

[virtual env folder name]/scripts/activate   [Enter]

**After Activating Virtualenv install Django:**
python -m pip install Django

check Django Version:---------
py -m django --version

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: it worked! I was just doing `pip install django`, instead of `python -m pip install Django`. Thanks a lot.